# Showing / hiding accessibility elements in an overflow menu when opening a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I’m implementing accessibility in a custom `UITableViewCell` class. I have a fairly simple overflow menu with a couple of buttons inside it, which are hidden until an ellipsis button is pushed that slides open and closes the overflow.

In my cell's initialiser I’m setting the `accessibilityElementsHidden` of my `overflowContainer` to `YES`. This seems to work, when scrolling through using VoiceOver, those views are skipped.

Then, when opening the cell, in the completion handler of the `UIView` animation, I set that same `accessibilityElementsHidden` of the same `overflowContainer` to NO. This doesn’t seem to have any effect, those elements are still skipped.

I’ve also tried posting `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, nil)` before / after / when changing the `accessibilityElementsHidden` `BOOL`, but this also appears to have no effect on the situation.

Basically I’d like to toggle `accessibilityElementsHidden` on a couple of `UIView` instances at a specific point. Could anyone let me know what I may be doing wrong?

Here’s the code I fire when the overflow opens:

```
- (void)cellOverflowDidShow:(MyCell *)cell
{
    self.overflowContainer.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.firstButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.secondButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.thirdButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, self.firstButton);
}
```

I fire the opposite when closing the cell (set all to `NO` and post notification again). And when initializing the cell, all I set is:

```
self.overflowContainer.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
```

Absolutely no idea why it shouldn’t be working, it appears I’m doing everything 100% correctly. If I don’t set the line in the initializer, the buttons all appear accessible (all the time). So it appears that the first call, be it `YES` or `NO`, works, but any subsequent ones are ignored.

Comment: This is a reach, but start by trying the screen change notification, instead.

Comment: No joy, alas, except that it resets the VoiceOver cursor back to the first element on the screen in that case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the visible state, you declare the overflow container to be an accessibility element. Thus, VoiceOver will allow the user to focus it rather than navigate child elements. Instead of toggling whether it's an accessibility element, keep `self.overflowContainer.isAccessibilityElement` set to `NO` and toggle the accessibility of its children, firstButton, secondButton, and thirdButton.

A shorthand for setting the accessibility of child elements is `accessibilityElementsHidden`. Try setting `self.overflowContainer.accessibilityElementsHidden` to `NO` when the view appears and `YES` when it disappears.

You may still need to trigger a layout change notification, regardless.

Comment: I’m afraid this hasn’t worked either. I’ve done exactly as described here – the container itself has `isAccessibilityElement` set to `NO`, the buttons themselves have `isAccessibilityElement` set to `YES`, and all I’m doing when opening and closing is toggling `accessibilityElementsHidden` on that container. No joy, buttons still aren’t seen when the panel opens. I’ve tried with the `Screen` and `Layout` notifications too.

Comment: In that case, treat the _entire_ table view cell as an accessibility container in order to override any default container behavior.

Comment: This doesn’t appear to work either. UIAccessibiliyContainer appears to be an old informal protocol with very sparse documentation, so I’m not really sure how I’d go about configuring certain elements to be accessible in certain circumstances without just replicating the initial issue. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: The `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol isn't dated or arcane, though the documentation can seem scattered. On your table view cell subclass, set or return `NO` for `isAccessibilityElement`, then implement all three informal protocol methods, taking care to return consistent values for `-accessibilityElementAtIndex:` and `-indexOfAccessibilityElement:`. Typically, containers are used to make non-view content, like complex rendered content and custom controls, accessible. Used here, it works around default table view cell accessibility.

Comment: Apple's Accessibility Programming Guide has a section titled ["Make the Contents of Custom Container Views Accessible"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW10).

Comment: As to whether this reproduces the original issue, well, yes, it might. You can't get around notifying accessibility clients to the new layout.

Comment: So I’ve been through the Apple guide and implemented the shown methods, none of them are actually ever called. I’m still telling it to show and hide its accessibility elements as I was before, but none of the UIAccessibilityContainer protocol methods are touched. Very confusing.

Comment: Just to confirm: they _are_ called if the elements are remain visible and are never hidden, correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. That’s how I’ve left it for the time being, so VoiceOver sees the buttons in the overflow whether it’s open or closed. If users are blind it’ll actually be perfectly functional for them, I don’t think Mail for instance even lets you open the overflow menu via VoiceOver. Shame though, I just don’t have the time to devote to further exploring it.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate your willingness to explore what could be wrong. This is something I intend to experiment with more in the future. Sorry I couldn't be of greater assistance.

Comment: Not a problem, I appreciate the help!