# iOS - Accessibility for images

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I am building out an app in iOS. I am working on accessibility and there is a logo on multiple screens that are cumbersome to go through continuously with VoiceOver. Is there a way for VoiceOver to not pick up the logo?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how its used, a logo can be very valuable for a screen reader user. They're often linked back to the home page or they're accompanied with the title of the site (which sometimes isn't represented elsewhere). If it provides this information or functionality, it's important not to remove it.

Instead, common practice is to provide a 'skip to content' button that allows keyboard/screen reader users to skip past repeating blocks of content and land on the main content area of the page. This is a good resource, although it's focused towards implementing on web: 
[skip navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259822/showing-hiding-a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bccessibility-element%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs-in-an-overflow-men%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bu-when-opening-a-cus%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bto)

I hope this can help.

Edit: The solution (if the above isn't applicable) is to set `isAccessibilityElement` to `no` as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259822/showing-hiding-a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bccessibility-element%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs-in-an-overflow-men%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bu-when-opening-a-cus%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bto) (as mentioned in the comment of this answer as the correct fix for the problem)

Comment: I have used skip navigation before on the web.  In general, I want a way for VoiceOver on my iPhone app to skip over certain blocks where it does not seem meaningful

Comment: like the equivalent of aria-hidden="true"

Comment: ah sorry to not answer your question. Have you tried setting 'isAccessibilityElement' to "no"? I'm not sure if it would help, but this question seems to have a similar approach: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259822/showing-hiding-accessibility-elements-in-an-overflow-menu-when-opening-a-custo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259822/showing-hiding-accessibility-elements-in-an-overflow-menu-when-opening-a-custo)

Comment: that worked. found that one earlier and forgot to add the solution. Thanks tho